# pseudo elemento after não vai para a direita

Tags: css, css3

Fiz uma `span` e dei `width` a ele de **800px**.

Coloquei um texto pequeno nele e adicionei um `after` na esperança de que esse afyer ficasseno final do `span` colado á direita.

Mas ficou **colado** ao texto, o que está errado?

```
  div.duvidas > div > span:after {
    display: inline-block;
    content: '+';
    width: 50px;
      height: 50px;
      line-height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cara tem muitas formas de alinhar o + a direita, vc tem que ver a que é melhor pro seu caso, pois vc pode colocar `float:right` no `::after`, ou mesmo `display:flex` no `span` e `margin-left: auto` no `::after` que é o que eu faria, até pq o `<span>` é um elemento `inline` e mesmo vc colocando `width` de `800px` ele não renderiza com `800px` pois por ser `inline` ele ocupa só o tamanho do texto que está dentro, e não o valor que vc determina como `width`

Veja a imagem para ver que 0 `800px` não aplica o `width`, pois o `<span>` é um elemento `inline`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Agora o código**

Segue uma opção para vc alinhar o `::after` a direita do *container*, colocando `display:flex` no `span` para ele ficar com os `800px` de fato, e `margin-left:auto` no `::after` para ele ir pro canto direito.

```css
span {
  width: 800px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  line-height: 50px;
  display: flex;
}

div.duvidas > div > span:after {
  display: inline-block;
  content: '+';
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="duvidas">
  <div>
      <span>Lorem ipsum dolor, officia!</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: de boa, obrigado! éra isso mesmo!

Comment: @CarlosRocha demoro tmj